# Multiple Nested Directories with Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this Makefile.

```
# Variables
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -c
ODUMP = objdump
ODFLAGS = -d

# Directories
OBJDIR := obj
TGTDIR := target
SRCDIR := src
DMPDIR := dump

# Sources list
SRCS := main.c kernel.c
# Sources location
VPATH := src:../headers

# Objects list
objects = $(notdir $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(SRCS))))
# Objects list with prefix
prefix_objs = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(objects))

# Target name
target = main

$(target) : $(prefix_objs)
    $(CC) -o $(TGTDIR)/$@ $(prefix_objs)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c | folders
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    $(ODUMP) $(ODFLAGS) $@ > $(DMPDIR)/$@

folders:
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    mkdir -p $(TGTDIR)
    mkdir -p $(DMPDIR)/$(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(TGTDIR) $(DMPDIR) *.o
```

I would like to be able to support at least one level deep "modules or features" nested under the src directory. I would also like to be able to stop having to manually build the `# Sources list` `SCRS := main.c kernel.c`
My folder structure is as follows

```
| dump
| obj
| src ----
    | kernel.c
    | kernel.h
    | main.c
| target
| .gitignore
| Makefile
| README.md
```

However, I would like to be able to support.

```
| dump
| obj
| src ----
    | kernel ----
        | kernel.h
        | thing.c
        | kernel.c
        | any.c
    | feature1 ----
        | ...whatever files
    | main.c
| target
| .gitignore
| Makefile
| README.md
```

If you look at my `folders` rule. I had to explicitly create the `$(DMPDIR)/$(OBJDIR)` because the `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` targets would get the prefix added, even for the dump files. If I start adding folders for my "features" I would need to support the mkdir for those as well since it would be `obj/kernel/kernal.o`. I also still need to list every file in SRCS... and now the recommended way of using `VPATH` has crumbled as well since it's no longer just `src`. It seems adding one new requirement has exploded the difficulty of extending this Makefile. Are there any GNU Make tricks to help with supporting nested directories?

Comment: Do you want to recreate the directory structure of `src/` in `obj/`?

Comment: @Beta I'm not particularly concerned with that. The structure might be nice incase i have duplicate file names i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all the source files in subdirectories and sub-subdirectories:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c $(SRCDIR)/*/*.c)
```

Why do the "objects" / "prefix_objects" thing?  Just make object files:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
```

Write a rule that creates object files in `obj` from source files in `src`.  Create the target directory:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
        @mkdir -p $(@D) $(DMPDIR)/$(@D)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
        $(ODUMP) $(ODFLAGS) $@ > $(DMPDIR)/$@
```

Fix your link line:

```
$(TGTDIR)/$(target) : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

If you really don't want to do the `mkdir` in the rule, you can use this: find all the directories containing objects, then create them:

```
OBJDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(OBJS)))

folders :
        mkdir -p $(TGTDIR) $(OBJDIRS) $(addprefix $(DMPDIR)/,$(OBJDIRS))
```

Comment: I added an edit for what was output from those changes.

Comment: nvm I see where I forgot the `OBJS := ...` step